# 2 Queries vs inner join with where

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 2 tables: Articles and Comments;
`"Comments.articleID"` is a foreign key.

I want to query the database to compose a website that shows the article text of a certain article (given an articleID) and all the article's comments.

I can think of 2 ways to query the data:

1. Use 2 separate queries:

   ```
   SELECT articles.text FROM articles where id = givenArticleID

   SELECT comments.* FROM comments where comments.articleID = givenArticleID
   ```
2. Use an Inner join:

   ```
    SELECT articles.text, comments.* 
    FROM articles 
    INNER JOIN comments on articles.id = comments.articleID 
    WHERE articles.id = givenArticleID
   ```

The first option only returns the data I am interested in - that is good.

The second option returns all data I am interested in, but much more data than necessary. Every row in the result set contains the article.text column, that could be a lot of (unnecessary) data.

I think that the join would be better for certain queries, that do not require a WHERE condition (thus containing different articles).

Which way would you generally prefer in the situation above?
Or is there an even better alternative...?

Comment: you use JOIN if you want to retrieve a related data or referenced from if not then don't use it.

Comment: Without commenting on these specific queries, in general it's preferable to strive for as few round trips to the database as possible

Comment: Tag properly!!!  MySQL <> Postgres

Comment: @maSTAShuFu Both tables are related by articleID... and they "belong" together... so wouldn't you say that a join is appropriate in this case?

Comment: the question is, did you want to display only the article or did you want also to display the comments?

Comment: @maSTAShuFu In the end, both, the article text and the comments (for this article) should be displayed on the same webpage.

Comment: What is the datatype of `articles.text` (if `text` datatype, what is the average size), and how many rows in `comments`?

Comment: @JoeFrizz so if both data are to be display then two tables are involved therefore you need to JOIN them.

Comment: @AaronDietz articles.text is TEXT and the number of comments could be up to 50... (so in its worst case, the result set is 49x articles.text of duplicated data)

Comment: It's a possibility that two queries are better - I'd follow Laurenz's advice and just try it both ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option 2 is probably better, because it is only one client-server round trip.

Also don't forget that each query has to be parsed by the database server.

I'd recommend that you benchmark both versions and see which one performs better.

Comment: Thanks. While Option 2 saves a roundtrip, the returned result set could be huge because the article text is delivered with each row... not sure whats better... thanks for helping

Comment: No guessing on our side can replace a simple benchmark that you can write in 5 minutes.